# Accessing array by reflection

Tags: .net, reflection

I created typed array in some object:

```
maket.GetType()
     .GetProperty(q.xmltags)
     .SetValue(maket,Array.CreateInstance(q.xmltag),0
      ), null);
```

Here i get that array:

```
var tag = maket.GetType().GetProperty(q.xmltags).GetValue(maket, null);
```

Now i want to add some element to that array, i try such code:

```
dynamic temp = tag;
tag = temp.ToList().Add(test).ToArray();
```

Obviously it doesn't work. How can i do it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are set on using the LINQ helpers, something like:

```
var list = Enumerable.ToList(temp);
list.Add(test);
tag = Enumerable.ToArray(list);
```

(then use reflection to set that back against the property) - however, this is a really expensive way to expand an array (at least, once it is repeated a few times). If you can **change the property to be a list** instead of an array, you can just use:

```
IList list = {reflection "get" code}
list.Add(test);
```

(with no need to "set" afterwards)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is getting an array, converting it to a list and then adding an element to that list. The original array stored in the property stays unmodified. Try setting your newly array back in the property using:

```
maket.GetType() 
 .GetProperty(q.ObjectType.xmltag) 
 .SetValue(maket, tag , null);
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe untyped array list can be useful

```
var arrayList = new ArrayList((Array)tag);
arrayList.Add(newValue);
tag = arrayList.ToArray((Type)q.xmltag);
```